# how to update nested List<Object> to a model in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, data-binding, model, nested-lists

I'm working on a web site that can manipulate some categories and subcategories

my model for each of the is :

```
  public class Category
  {
    [Key]
    public int Categoryid { get; set; }
    [Required , StringLength(50)]
    public string Categoryname { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public static string  Serialize(Category cat)
    {
      string jObject= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cat);
      return jObject;
    }

    public static Category DeSerialize(string cat)
    {
      Category Dcat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Category>(cat);
      return Dcat;
    }
  }
```

--

```
  public class SubCategory
  {

    [Key]
    public int SubCategoryid { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public string SubCategoryname { get; set; }
    public int Categoryid { get; set; }

    public SubCategory( string name)
    {
      SubCategoryname = name;
    }
    public SubCategory()
    {

    }
  }
```

And my Action that edit/create the subcategories and Categories t is :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, string txtSub, string subCreate, string saveAll)
    {
      Category Cat = context.Categories.Single(cat => cat.Categoryid == id);
      UpdateModel(Cat, new string[] { "Categoryname "});

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

          // Create Sub
          if (subCreate!= null)
          {
            if (txtSub != "")
            {
              context.SubCategories.Add(new SubCategory(txtSub) { Categoryid = Cat.Categoryid });
              context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Edit");
          }
          if (saveAll!= null)
          {
            // Edit Sub/Cat
            for (int i = 0; i < Cat.SubCategories.Count; i++)
            {
              context.Entry(Cat.SubCategories[i]).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            context.Entry(Cat).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("index");
          }

        }
        return View();
    }
```

so the Problem is I cant update specifically the name of my SubCategories because it a nested List of

custom object ....

I read I could specify the logic in the modelupdate() but i just cant do it .

I tried to add

this model updater :

```
UpdateModel(Cat.SubCategories, new string[] { "SubCategories.SubCategoryname" });
```

this model updater :

```
for(int i = 0;iCat.SubCategories.Count;i++)
{
    UpdateModel(Cat.SubCategories[0], new string[] { "SubCategories.SubCategoryname" });
}
```

this model updater :

```
for(int i = 0;iCat.SubCategories.Count;i++)
{
    UpdateModel(Cat.SubCategories[0], new string[] { "SubCategories.SubCategoryname" });
}
```

this model updater :

```
for(int i = 0;iCat.SubCategories.Count;i++)
{
    UpdateModel(Cat.SubCategories[0], new string[] { "SubCategories["+i+"].SubCategoryname" });
}
```

I know it possible cause when I'm only doing updateModel(Cat) everyting is greatly binded and work

.But for a security reason I want to only doint it on name of the model, not on ids .

all of them didn't work . so im shure im just missing up a little mistake! Thanks

for your TIME!

Comment: Cant understand what your doing here. Why aren't you just binding to your model and posting it back. What are `Serialize` and `DeSerialize` methods? You need to include your view.

Comment: yeah hummm Serialize and DeSerialize is just for posting an object :P but i finaly dont use it .... if y only bind all my data to my model it just to easy to hack it. that why in only sending an id